# Android Sqlite Table not created even create table query executed successfully

Tags: android, sqlite

In my project My create table query executed successfully when i debug with break points.. but when i saw in File explorer->mnt->sdcard->android->Mydbname->mydbname.db  no tables are created there.. I also checked in data->data->package name->.... I created db using sqlite admin.

```
// Database name definitions
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MMPDB.db";

    // Table name definitions
    public static final String LOG_IN_TABLE = "LogIn";
    public static final String FI_GOODS_DETAIL_TABLE = "fiGoodDetail";
    public static final String FI_GOODS_SUMMARY_TABLE = "fiGoodSummary";
    public static final String ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE = "itemDetail";
    public static final String SETTINGS_TABLE = "Setting";

    // LogIn table fields declaration
    public static final String LOGIN_USERNAME = "userName";
    public static final String LOGIN_PASSWORD = "password";

    // fiGoodDetail table fields declaration
    public static final String FIGOODSDETAIL_FINISHGOODS = "fiGoods";
    public static final String FIGOODSDETAIL_ITEMDESC = "itemDesc";
    public static final String FIGOODSDETAIL_FINISHQTY = "fiQty";
    public static final String FIGOODSDETAIL_FINISHUNITWEIGHT = "fiUnitWeight";
    public static final String FIGOODSDETAIL_FINISHTOTALWEIGHT = "fiTotalWeight";
    public static final String FIGOODSDETAIL_LOTBINNUM = "lotBinNum";

    // fiGoodSummary table fields declaration
    public static final String FIGOODSSUMMARY_FINISHGOODS = "fiGoods";
    public static final String FIGOODSSUMMARY_FINISHQTY = "fiQty";
    public static final String FIGOODSSUMMARY_FINISHUNITWEIGHT = "fiUnitWeight";
    public static final String FIGOODSSUMMARY_FINISHTOTALWEIGHT = "fiTotalWeight";
    public static final String FIGOODSSUMMARY_ITEMDESC = "itemDesc";
    public static final String FIGOODSSUMMARY_QTYUM = "qtyUm";
    public static final String FIGOODSSUMMARY_QTY = "qty";
    public static final String FIGOODSSUMMARY_YIELD = "yield";

    // itemDesc table fields declaration
    public static final String ITEMDETAIL_FINISHGOODS = "fiGoods";
    public static final String ITEMDETAIL_ITEMDESC = "itemDesc";
    public static final String ITEMDETAIL_LOCTID = "loctId";
    public static final String ITEMDETAIL_LOTBINNUM = "lotBinNum";
    public static final String ITEMDETAIL_QTYUM = "qtyUm";
    public static final String ITEMDETAIL_QTYUMUSED = "qtyUmUsed";
    public static final String ITEMDETAIL_YIELD = "yield";
    public static final String ITEMDETAIL_ACTUALQTY = "actQty";
    public static final String ITEMDETAIL_ACTUALSCARP = "actScrp";
    public static final String ITEMDETAIL_UNITCOST = "unitCost";
    public static final String ITEMDETAIL_TOTALCOST = "totalCost";

    // Setting table fields declaration
    public static final String SETTINGS_SERVERPATH = "serverPath";
//  public static final String SETTINGS_COMPANY="company";

    // Creation of Query for Each Table.
    // tlogin table creation query
    public static final String LOG_IN_TABLE_CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE "
            + LOG_IN_TABLE + "(" + LOGIN_USERNAME + " TEXT," 
            + LOGIN_PASSWORD + " TEXT);";

    // tfigodet table creation query
    public static final String FI_GOODS_DETAIL_TABLE_CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE "
            + FI_GOODS_DETAIL_TABLE + "(" + FIGOODSDETAIL_FINISHGOODS + " TEXT,"
            + FIGOODSDETAIL_ITEMDESC + " TEXT,"
            + FIGOODSDETAIL_FINISHQTY + " TEXT,"
            + FIGOODSDETAIL_FINISHUNITWEIGHT + " TEXT,"
            + FIGOODSDETAIL_FINISHTOTALWEIGHT + " TEXT,"
            + FIGOODSDETAIL_LOTBINNUM + " TEXT);";

    // tfigosum table creation query
    public static final String FI_GOODS_SUMMARY_TABLE_CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE "
            + FI_GOODS_SUMMARY_TABLE
            + "("
            + FIGOODSSUMMARY_FINISHGOODS
            + " TEXT,"
            + FIGOODSSUMMARY_FINISHQTY
            + " TEXT,"
            + FIGOODSSUMMARY_FINISHUNITWEIGHT
            + " TEXT,"
            + FIGOODSSUMMARY_FINISHTOTALWEIGHT
            + " TEXT,"
            + FIGOODSSUMMARY_ITEMDESC
            + " TEXT,"
            + FIGOODSSUMMARY_QTYUM
            + " TEXT,"
            + FIGOODSSUMMARY_QTY
            + " TEXT,"
            + FIGOODSSUMMARY_YIELD
            + " TEXT);";

    // titemdet table creation query
    public static final String ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE_CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE "
            + ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE + "(" + ITEMDETAIL_FINISHGOODS + " TEXT,"
            + ITEMDETAIL_ITEMDESC + " TEXT," + ITEMDETAIL_LOCTID + " TEXT,"
            + ITEMDETAIL_LOTBINNUM + " TEXT," + ITEMDETAIL_QTYUM + " TEXT,"
            + ITEMDETAIL_YIELD + " TEXT," + ITEMDETAIL_ACTUALQTY + " TEXT,"
            + ITEMDETAIL_QTYUMUSED + " TEXT," + ITEMDETAIL_ACTUALSCARP + " TEXT,"
            + ITEMDETAIL_UNITCOST + " TEXT," + ITEMDETAIL_TOTALCOST + " TEXT);";

    // tsettings table creation query
    public static final String SETTINGS_TABLE_CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE "
            + SETTINGS_TABLE + "(" + SETTINGS_SERVERPATH + " TEXT);";

    // Constructor to create Database
    public MmpDBHelper(Context context) {
        DATABASE_FILE_PATH = new File(Supporter.getAppCommonPath(),
                DATABASE_NAME);

        if (!DATABASE_FILE_PATH.exists()) {

            try {

                db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_FILE_PATH,
                        null);
                // openDatabase();
                db.beginTransaction();
                db.execSQL(LOG_IN_TABLE_CREATE_QUERY);
                db.execSQL(FI_GOODS_DETAIL_TABLE_CREATE_QUERY);
                db.execSQL(FI_GOODS_SUMMARY_TABLE_CREATE_QUERY);
                db.execSQL(ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE_CREATE_QUERY);
                db.execSQL(SETTINGS_TABLE_CREATE_QUERY);

                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                Log.i("Success", "All tables created successfully");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                db.endTransaction();
                errCode = "Error 501";
                msg = "Table creation failed";
                errMsg = errCode + " : " + msg;
                LogFileCreator.appendLog(errMsg);
            } finally {
//              db.endTransaction();
                db.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Adding your code to your question would be helpful

Comment: put code you have tried

Comment: Just now added . Kindly check.

Comment: @SivaBala: i think you need to add space between `,` and next column name in create table query

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K but while debugging there is no error in that QUERY

Comment: First u have to run one query then it will create table just put one query in 
 `MainActivity` which is run first for select from any table then see your database u will find you all table in it

Comment: Why dont you use SqliteOpenHelper?